# Having an ivar 'delegate' in a subclass whose superclass also has same named ivar

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, warnings, uitextviewdelegate

I have a subclass defined like this

```
@protocol UMTextViewDelegate;

@interface UMTexView : UITextView <UITextViewDelegate> {

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<UMTextViewDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol UMTextViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)textViewDidSelectWordToDefine:(UMTexView*)textView;
@end
```

But I get a warning `Property type 'id<UMTextViewDelegate>' is incompatible with type 'id<UITextViewDelegate>' inherited from 'UITextView'`.

How do I suppress this warning ? I tried adding this :

```
@protocol UMTextViewDelegate <NSObject, UITextViewDelegate>
```

but no luck. !!

EDIT:

I am not using ARC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is about forward declarations. In the place where you are declaring the `delegate`, the compiler doesn't know that `UMTextViewDelegate` descends from `UITextViewDelegate`. The only thing it knows is that `UMTextViewDelegate` is a protocol.

You have to create a forward declaration for the class `@class UMTexView;`, then put the protocol declaration and then the class declaration.

On a separate note, it's obvious `UMTexView` is supposed to be the text delegate for itself. Maybe it would be easier to have `UMTexView` descending directly from `UIView` and put an `UITextView` inside it. Then you wouldn't have any problem with delegate collisions and the `UITextViewDelegate` would be unaccessible externally.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Sulthan's answer, this is what I came up with and it squished the warning.

```
@class UMTextView;

@protocol UMTextViewDelegate <NSObject, UITextViewDelegate>
@optional
- (void)textViewDidSelectWordToDefine:(UMTextView*)textView;
@end

@interface UMTextView : UITextView <UITextViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<UMTextViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

The forward declaration of UMTextView followed by protocol declaration tells UMTextView that UMTextViewDelegate is indeed descends from UITextViewDelegate. That way I don't have to the route of adding a `uiview` and then adding a `uitextview` inside that view.